# How to use an if/ else statement

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get my program to ask the user if they wish to get "Super feet", if yes then it will proceed but if no then the program should say thank you. Can some help me identify what I did wrong? Thank you.

```
Console.Write("Would you like the super feet as well? ");
Console.ReadLine();

bool yes = true;
if (yes == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the following dims: ");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ok, Thank you");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: You didn't capture what they typed in which is what `Console.ReadLine()` returns.

Comment: `yes` will *always* be `true` because you set it to `true` and never change it.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading your answer before the condition is tested.  Also you need to store your answer in a variable.

```
Console.Write("Would you like the super feet as well? ");
var ans = Console.ReadLine();

bool yes = (ans == "yes");
if (yes == true)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter the following dims: ");
  ...Code if yes is true...


}
   else
{
  Console.WriteLine("Ok, Thank you");
  ...Code if yes is false...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you did 2 things wrong:

1. You are not reading any input from user, in order to do that, you have do something like:

   ```
   string answer = Console.ReadLine();
   ```
2. you are not assigning value to bool variable yes based on this input, so, you have to do something like

   ```
   if(answer == "yes")
       yes = true;
   else
       yes = false;
   ```

So, there, after inserting these two into your code, it will looke like:

```
    Console.Write("Would you like the super feet as well? ");
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();

    bool yes;
    if(answer == "yes")
        yes = true;
    else
        yes = false;

    if (yes == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the following dims: ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ok, Thank you");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Of course, you might also like to assign true to the bool variable yes, if the answer is like "Yes", "yES" and so on, in order to do that, you can use `answer = answer.ToLower()`

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
Console.Write("Would you like the super feet as well? ");
string s =  Console.ReadLine();

///bool yes = true;
if (s.ToLower() == "yes")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the following dims: ");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ok, Thank you");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```